# React - check if a object is in state variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a state variable that is a object (called testObject). I store several objects in that state variable. Iam looking for a way to check if a object already exists in that state variable then remove it if true.

so to sum up the dilemma:

- check if a object is already in testObject
- If true => delete that object
- if false => add the object to testObject

  class Connector extends Component {

  ```
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state=({
          testObject: {},
      });

      console.log(this.props);
  }
  ```

  }

Comment: Do you want to check a non-empty object or a particular key in the `testObject` ?

Comment: Yes a non empty object

Comment: you can check using this `Object.keys(obj).length`

Comment: can you explain why you are doing this? I think there may be a better way, react state must be immutable. Are you looking for "replacing" the object inside your testObject by any chance?

Comment: yes i want to replace the object inside testObject, so it doesnt get added as duplicate

Answer (score 0):

How about toggling the state?

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  testObject: {
    ...prevState.testObject,
    someProperty: !prevState.testObject.someProperty
  }
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check it by this way:

```
if (this.state.testObject.hasOwnProperty(property_name))
  delete this.state.testObject.property_name
else {
  var testObject = this.state.testObject
  testObject[property_name] = some_value
  this.setState({testObject: testObject})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will delete the testObject key from the state if present.

Assuming that `obj` is the object you want to delete/add.

```
let newState = this.state.testObject

if (this.state.testObject.obj) {
    delete newState["obj"]
} else {
    newObject["obj"] = "value"
}

this.setState({ testObject: newState })
```

if the `obj` is present in testObject, then it will delete it, else it will insert `obj` in testObject.

Answer (score 0):

lets say the object in question is in testObject with key obj and the incoming var is newTestObj.

then we will check

```
if(this.state.testObject && this.state.testObject.obj) {
   let tempObj = this.state.testObject;
   delete tempObj.obj;
   this.setState({
      testObject: tempObj
   })
}else {
  this.setState({
      testObject: {...testObject, obj: newTestObj.obj}
   })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use an if statement to check if the object exists.

```
if(this.state.objectName)
  delete this.state.objectName
```

Comment: @Luis Van Senden. You cant delete object from react state with your approach.